# Using Racket BSL to design a World program that allows a user to customize a face upon a "menu" of options for eyes, mouth, and hair

Tags: racket

TODO: design the World program bit-face to allow
someone to customize a face based upon a "menu"
of options for eyes, mouth, and hair.

You should have (at least) three options for eyes,
three options for mouth, and three options for hair.
Each time the user presses the "e" key, they should
see the next option for eyes (cycling as necessary);
same with "m" for mouth and "h" for hair. The
bit-face function should supply initial values for
each of these face features.

Images are random eyes, mouth, and hair images from the internet.

I can't seem to figure out how to cycle the eyes, mouth, and hair using on-key and am not sure how to use the to-draw in this specific scenario.

This is what I have so far using Racket BSL:

```
(require 2htdp/image)
(require 2htdp/universe)

(define EYES-1 [image here])
(define EYES-2 [image here])
(define EYES-3 [image here])

(define MOUTH-1 [image here])
(define MOUTH-2 [image here])
(define MOUTH-3 [image here])

(define HAIR-1 [image here])
(define HAIR-2 [image here])
(define HAIR-3 [image here])

(define-struct bf [eyes mouth hair])

; A BitFace (BF) is a (make-bf Image Image Image)
; Interpretation: customizable face based upon a
; menu of eyes, mouth, and hair

(define BF-1
  (make-bf EYES-1 MOUTH-1 HAIR-1))

(define BF-2
  (make-bf EYES-2 MOUTH-2 HAIR-2))

(define BF-3
  (make-bf EYES-3 MOUTH-3 HAIR-3))

(define (bf-temp bf)
  (... (bf-eyes bf) ...
       (bf-mouth bf) ...
       (bf-hair bf) ...))

; bit-face : Image Image Image -> Image
; creates a customized face based upon a "menu"

(define (bit-face e m h)
  (big-bang (make-bf e m h)
    [to-draw draw-bf]))

; Wishlist:
; - draw-bf
; - key-bf

; draw-bf : BF -> Image
; visualize a bit face

(define (draw-bf bf)
  (place-image
   (circle 100 "outline" "black")
   150 150
   (empty-scene 300 300)))

; key-bf : BF KeyEvent -> BF
; cycle the eyes, mouth, and
; hair when keys are pressed

(define (key-bf bf)
  (... (bf-eyes bf) ...
       (bf-mouth bf) ...
       (bf-hair bf) ...))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is big-bang, I think you should use on-key function. It is kind of similar like we have done for the color changing before. This time we are going to rotate the images not color. You can probably start with that.